# Can't do the conversion from binary to ascii in C language

Tags: c, file

I had an assignment at school in C language in working with files. I have a file with .dat extension to modify using the following code. In the .dat file there are information about students (which have the Student struct).

With this code I have to add some points to one grade that the students have after I input a certain dept(class) number in the console.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { 
    int code; 
    char name[30]; 
    int year; 
    int dept; 
    int number; 
    int grade[15]; 
}Student;

void main(){ 
    FILE * f; 
    char s1[20]; 
    Student s; 
    int n, i;
    printf("\nFile: "); 
    gets_s(s1);

    if(!(f = fopen(s1, "rb+")))  printf("\nThe file %s cannot be open", s1);
    else{
        printf("\nClass: "); scanf("%d",&n);
        while(!feof(stdin)){
            rewind(f);
            fread(&s, sizeof(Student), 1, f);
            i = 0;
            while(!feof(f)){
                if(n == s.dept){
                    i = 1;
                    s.grade[0] = (s.grade[0] == 10) ? s.grade[0] : s.grade[0] + 1;
                    fseek(f, ftell(f) - sizeof(Student), 0);
                    fwrite(&s, sizeof(Student), 1, f);
                    fseek(f, 0, 1);
                }
                fread(&s, sizeof(Student), 1, f);
            }
            if(!i) printf("\n No student found in class %d", s.dept);
            printf("\nClass: "); scanf("%d",&n);
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
}
```

All good but in the console I get a strange dept number.

```
File: stud.dat

Class: 200

 No student found in class -858993460
```

I think this is happening because there is no conversion from binary to ascii. I searched the internet and I didn`t find anything that can help me. Is there a function I need to insert or something like this?

Thank you!

stud.dat file

```
e   smith þþþþþþþþþþþþ   1            ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌf   james þþþþþþþþþþþþ   ,           ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌg   mike þþþþþþþþþþþ   ê            
   ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌh   jon þþþþþþþþþþþþþþþþ   m         
   ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
```

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code::

1. assumes I understand what the OP is trying to do.
2. cleanly compiles
3. performs the (as understood) functionality
4. properly checks for errors

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_FILENAME_LEN 20
#define MAX_STUDENT_NAME_LEN 30
#define MAX_GRADES  15

struct STUDENT
{
    int code;
    char name[ MAX_STUDENT_NAME_LEN ];
    int year;
    int dept;
    int number;
    int grade[ MAX_GRADES ];
};
typedef struct STUDENT Student;


int main( void )
{
    FILE * f;
    char filename[ MAX_FILE_NAME_LEN ];
    Student s;
    int dept;

    printf( "\nFile: " );
    fflush( stdout );
    if( !fgets( filename, sizeof( filename ), stdin ) )
    {
        perror( "fgets for file name failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fgets successful

    // remove trailing newline
    filename[ strspn( filename, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

    if( !(f = fopen( filename, "rb+" )))
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        fprintf( stderr, "\nThe file %s cannot be open", filename );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    printf( "\nClass: " );  // AKA dept
    fflush( stdout );
    if( scanf("%d",&dept) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for class failed\n" );
        fclose( f ); // cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    int found = 0;

    while( fread( &s, sizeof(Student), 1, f ) == 1 )
    {
        if( dept == s.dept )
        {
            found = 1;
            s.grade[0] =  s.grade[0] == 10 ) ? s.grade[0] : s.grade[0] + 1;
            if( fseek(f, -(long int)(sizeof(Student)), SEEK_CUR) != 0 )
            {
                perror( "fseek failed" );
                fclose( f );  // cleanup
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            // implied else, fseek successful

            if( fwrite( &s, sizeof( Student ), 1, f ) != 1 )
            {
                perror( "fwrite failed" );
                fclose( f );  // cleanup
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            // implied else, fwrite successful
        }
    }

    fclose( f );

    if( !found )
    {
        printf( "\n No student found in class %d\n", dept );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I ran your code and I got this: `File: stud.dat
fopen failed: Invalid argument

The file  cannot be openPress any key to continue . . .`